# WidgetSpan is not proper align in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I want to set a black heart between "m" and "ms". and also I want to use "TextAlign.justify". if I use "TextAlign.center" then it's working fine. but if I use "TextAlign.justify" so the black heart is not set in the correct place. If I remove the "WidgetSpan" widget and add "TextSpan" for a black heart so also it's working. but I want to add bottom padding.
Please guys help me.
Thanks

[image]

```
Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: <InlineSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                      text: MyString.txtAboutUs ,

                     style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: FontSize.size14,
                          fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_regular)),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: " m",
                      children: <InlineSpan>[
                        WidgetSpan(
                          baseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                            alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                              child: Text("", style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: FontSize.size8,
                                  fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_regular) ),
                            )
                        ),
                       
                        TextSpan(
                            text: "ms ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: FontSize.size14,
                                fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_medium,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      ],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: FontSize.size14,
                          fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_medium,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),


                  TextSpan(
                      text: MyString.txtAboutImmediately,

                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: FontSize.size14,
                          fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_regular)),
                ],
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to below simple Text Widget

```
Text('you add  here'),
// OR 
Text('you add \u{2764} here} '),
```

Updated Answer using **RichText**

```
Center(
          child: Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(
          text: 'You add ',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 10.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: '',
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Here',
        ),
      ],
    ),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0,),
  ),
),
```

Screen like
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want to set a small size for only the heart.

Comment: Ok you want Text size is large then heart icon ?

Comment: I already did the same, Please use " textAlign: TextAlign.justify" then after check. Please check my question again I think you are missing my exect point.

Comment: What you want ? I Update my answer Using RichText and output screen also can you try this, Or your problem is solved?

Comment: Can you please set the heart veritcal center in between "You add" and "here!". right now in your output, the heart is looking like in the bottom.

Comment: Please copy my code in try this you get a better idea of what is the issue.

Comment: Please check my updated answer using Text.rich() hope your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

replace `padding` with `transform`.

```
  WidgetSpan(
                      baseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
                      alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.top,
                      child: Container(
                        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0, -3, 0),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                        child: Text(
                          "",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              // fontSize: FontSize.size8,
                              // fontFamily: MyFont.poppins_regular,

                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```